# Credit card checker luhn algorithm javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, credit-card

I'm currently making a credit card checker([Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)) from the [Codecademy project](https://www.codecademy.com/paths/full-stack-engineer-career-path/tracks/fscp-javascript-syntax-part-ii/modules/fecp-challenge-project-mysterious-organism/projects/mysterious-organism) but my function does not seem to work, because it gives me back "false" with an array that has to return "true"(valid3). Can anyone helps me?

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5];

// Add your functions below:

function validateCred(arr) {
  let reverseArr = arr.reverse()
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < reverseArr.length; i += 2) {
    sum += reverseArr[i];
    sum += reverseArr[i + 1] * 2;
    if (reverseArr[i + 1] * 2 > 9) {
      sum -= 9;
    }
  }
  if (sum % 10 === 0) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

function findInvalidCards(arr000) {
  let invalidArr = []
  for (let j = 0; j < arr000.length; j++) {
    if (validateCred(arr000[j]) === false) {
      invalidArr.push(arr000[j])
    }
  }
  return invalidArr;
}

let arr = [4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 8, 6, 8, 9, 9, 8, 5]
let arr1 = 6
console.log(validateCred(valid3))

console.log(findInvalidCards(batch))
```

Comment: You're missing `invalid4`

Comment: just edited; thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valid3` has an odd number of elements so `reverseArr[i + 1]` becomes undefined in validateCred. Perhaps you can check that reverseArr[i + 1] has a value before adding it to the sum:

```js
// All valid credit card numbers
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];
const valid2 = [5, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1, 4, 3, 9];
const valid3 = [3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 1, 9, 9, 8, 5, 2, 3, 6];
const valid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 2, 9, 0, 5];
const valid5 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 4, 0, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 6, 6];

// All invalid credit card numbers
const invalid1 = [4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 1, 0, 9, 1, 7, 9, 5];
const invalid2 = [5, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3];
const invalid3 = [3, 7, 5, 7, 9, 6, 0, 8, 4, 4, 5, 9, 9, 1, 4];
const invalid4 = [6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7, 7, 7, 9, 3, 5];
const invalid5 = [5, 3, 8, 2, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 2, 8, 8, 3, 8, 5, 4];

// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5];

// Add your functions below:

function validateCred(arr) {
  let reverseArr = [...arr].reverse()
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < reverseArr.length; i += 2) {
    sum += reverseArr[i];
    
    if(reverseArr[i + 1]) { // Check reverseArr[i + 1] has a value
      sum += reverseArr[i + 1] * 2;
      if (reverseArr[i + 1] * 2 > 9) {
        sum -= 9;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return sum % 10 === 0;
}


console.log(batch.map(validateCred))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my JavaScript port of our server side algorithm:

```js
function luhnCheck(s) {
  // Strip the dashses and other garbage
  let ccNumber = s.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    
  // We need at least 14 digits for a valid card number
  // Check for a blank string because it would return true
  if (!ccNumber || ccNumber.length < 14) return false;
  if (ccNumber.length == 14 && !ccNumber.matches(/^3(?:0[0-59]{1}|[689])[0-9]{0,}$/)) return false;

  let sum = 0;
  let alternate = false;
  for (let i = ccNumber.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let n = parseInt(ccNumber.substring(i, i + 1));    
      if (alternate) {
        n *= 2;
        if (n > 9) {
          n = (n % 10) + 1;
        }
      }
      sum += n;
      alternate = !alternate;
  }
  return (sum % 10 == 0);
}
```